# What is the difference between $P(S = s, N = n )$ vs $P(S = s | N =n)$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

What is the difference between $P(S = s, N = n )$ vs $P(S = s | N =n)$?
I know the former is a joint probability and the latter is a conditional probability, and that $P(S=s, N=n) = P(S=s | N=n)P(N=n)$; however, I can't seem to distinguish between the meaning of the 2 in certain problems.

For this discussion, let's consider $S$ to be the random variable for the sum of numbers we draw from a hat. $N$ is the number of draws. Let's just say we draw with replacement for simplicity.

So $P(S=s, N=n)$, in words, is the probability that we draw $n$ times AND the sum of the $n$ draws is $s$. $P(S=s | N=n)$, in words, is the probability of drawing a sum $s$ given that we draw $n$ times. The two in this situation sounds identical to me, which would imply $P(N=n)=1$. But is this really the case, or am I not understand this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an event of

1. Drawing a specific sum from the hat
2. Drawing from the hat a specific number of times

and then a compound event of drawing from the hat a specific number of times **and** drawing a specific sum.

You need to carefully determine what your **universal set** $U$ is -- the set whose cardinality you put in the denominator to calculate probabilities. Suppose the number of draws, $n_{i\ge1}$, belongs to a finite set $P=\{n_1,n_2,...,n_m\}$, and the numbers in the hat are from the set $X$.

1. While calculating $P(S=s, N=n_1)$, each instance of $n_1$ draws yielding $s$ sum is accounted in the numerator, i.e. the number of $n_1$-tuples adding up to $s$,$$\sum_{x_1+x_2+...+x_{n_1}=s\\x_i\in X}1$$and each instance of any sum being obtained after any number of draws is accounted in the denominator (which is your compound event), i.e. the number of tuples of any length $n_i\in P$,$$|U|=|S=s,N=n_1|+|S\neq s,N=n_1|+|S=s,N\neq n_1|+|S\neq s,N\neq n_1|\\=\sum_{i=1}^m|X|^{n_i}$$
2. While calculating $P(S=s|N=n_1)$, the universal set is restricted to only $n_1$-tuples. You add only those $n_1$-tuples whose sum is $s$ in the numerator, i.e.$$\sum_{x_1+x_2+...+x_{n_1}=s\\x_i\in X}1$$ and all $n_1$-tuples in the denominator, i.e.$$|U|=|N=n_1|=|S=s,N=n_1|+|S\neq s,N=n_1|=|X|^{n_1}$$

Indeed, when the only element of $P$ is $n_1, P(N=n_1)=1/m=1$ and both the probabilities are identical.

Comment: Hmm I've never viewed it this way before. So the gist is, the numerator in both cases is the same, but the denominator is what changes?

Comment: That much is clear from the expression of conditional probability -- $P(S=s|N=n)=\frac{P(S=s\text{ and }N=n)}{P(N=n)}$ -- the numerator is pretty much $P(S=s, N=n)$. The gist is that you have disregarded the possibility that one could draw various quantities of numbers from the hat, say $n_1,n_2,..,n_m$ with equal probability $1/m$.

Comment: "the possibility that one could draw various quantities of numbers from the hat." ahh yes, I think that's exactly what I did. If someone asks me the question "What is the probability of making $n$ draws and having the sum of those $n$ draws be $S=s$?" am I solving for $P(S=s | N=n)$ instead of $P(S = s, N = n)$ in this case?

Comment: You should be solving for $P(S=s,N=n)$ which by its very definition is interpreted as $P(S=s\text{ and }N=n)$.

Comment: What if the question was instead phrased as "What is the probability that in $n$ draws, the sum $S=s$?" I think this is now aligned with the conditional probability.

Comment: Absolutely! In your earlier phrase, you said: what is the probability of MAKING $n$ DRAWS and HAVING THEIR SUM $s$ -- clearly, the probability of making $n$ draws should also be factored in. But now, it is given that you limit your scope to $n$ draws only.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly simpler example which may help clarify.  Consider a regular six-sided die as the sample space.

Let $S$ be the event "odd", as in $1,3,$ or $5$ thrown.

Let $N$ be the event "greater than 4", as in $5$ or $6$ thrown.

Now, $P\left(S=\text{"true"},N=\text{"true"}\right)=\frac{1}{6}$ because there is only one outcome out of $6$ where the result is "odd" *and* greater than $4$, namely throwing the number $5$.

Now, consider the case where we are **given** that the number thrown was greater than 4.  What is the probability that the number thrown was odd?  In this case, there are only two possible numbers greater than $4$, namely $5$ or $6$.  Therefore, with the additional information that we were given, the probability that the result is odd is now $\frac{1}{2}$:

$P\left(S="true" | N="true"\right) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Because we are given additional information, that reduces the size of the sample space to consider.  We went from all $6$ possibilities in the first case, to only $2$ in the second case.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. So I do understand it in this context. But in my particular example that I give I am having trouble distinguishing between the two. But after reading this simple example, I'm thinking about the former problem again, and I think it makes sense to me now. In the original problem, I can essentially view $P(S = s | N =n)$ as the probability of $P(S = s, N=n)$ over the sample space where $N = n$ is true, which is the definition of conditional probability.